# Powershell: Remove all between 2 strings

Tags: regex, powershell

got a html which contains 2 lines of texts.

```
<!-- START -->
asdf
<!-- END -->
```

between those 2 marker can stand anything and its changing data so its not same data all the time.
Is there a possibility to erase all lines between those 2?

Have tried with regex

```
(?sm)<!-- START -->.*?(?=^<!-- END -->)
```

but he always starts with the first line and not below.

Can someone help me to start after  with regex and then delete it?

Comment: Use a parser that understands HTML. A [regex doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/503046) work with HTML. Try, say, `html agility pack`.

Comment: But hes stopping right only the beginning is wrong

Comment: It will not select the second line due to the lookahead `(?=^<!-- END -->)` You could try a capturing group and use the group in the replacement `(?sm)<!-- START -->\r?\n(.*?)\r?\n<!-- END -->` https://regex101.com/r/CGun4i/1 but html and regex is usually not a good combination.

Comment: yes done that its working 
`$regex=@'
(?ms)^(\s*<!-- OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES START -->\s*?\r?\n).*?\r?\n(\s*<!-- OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES END -->\s*)
'@
$delete = (Get-Content -raw $file) -replace $regex, '$1$2'
$delete |Set-Content C:\Users\marku\Desktop\GEA\Powershell\mdi-opc-items.html`

Comment: @s0Nic Ah yes, I suggested it the other way around :-) Wiktor Stribiżew provided the right answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you match without capturing the left-hand delimiter.

To match and erase arbitrary content in between two multichar delimiters you need to either put both delimiters inside lookarounds:

```
-replace '(?<=left_hand_delim).*?(?=right_hand_delim)'
```

Or, use capturing groups in the regex and backreferences in the replacement:

```
-replace '(left_hand_delim).*?(right_hand_delim)', '$1$2'
```

You may use

```
$regex='(?ms)(?<=^\s*<!-- OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES START -->\s*).*?(?=\s*<!-- OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES END -->)'
(Get-Content -raw $file) -replace $regex, '$1$2' | Set-Content $outfile
```

See [regex demo 1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5Cs*%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20START%20--%3E%5Cs*%29.*%3F%28%3F%3D%5Cs*%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20END%20--%3E%29&i=%20%20%20%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20START%20--%3E%20%20some%20text%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20END%20--%3E&r=) and [regex demo #2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5E%5Cs*%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20START%20--%3E%5Cs*%29.*%3F%28%5Cs*%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20END%20--%3E%29&i=%20%20%20%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20START%20--%3E%20%20some%20text%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C!--%20OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES%20END%20--%3E&r=%241%242) (see *Context* tab).

You must use `-raw` option to read in the file contents into a single variable since you need the `s` singleline flag to let `.` match any char including newlines.